# Problemas con DevExpress

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress

Lo que pasa es que estoy elaborando una aplicación web que incluye DevExpress en la versión 15.1.7.0 y me da error al momento de compilar :

> Mensaje de error del compilador: BC30009: Es necesaria una referencia
>   al ensamblado 'DevExpress.Data.v15.1, Version=15.1.7.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' que contenga la
>   interfaz implementada 'DevExpress.Utils.IAssignableCollection'.
>   Agregue una al proyecto.

Pero ya tengo agregada la referencia a mi proyecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mismo error te esta diciendo la solución, te falta la referencia a "DevExpress.Data" y "DevExpress.Utils".

Comment: Tienes razón, es que yo la tenia el DevExpress.Data como referencia en el proyecto , pero no aparecía su referencia en el web.config, solo me quedo agregarlo ahí y se soluciono.

Answer (score 1):

Cosas raras del DevExpress... Te recomiendo que re-instales el componente, hagas un 'Clean' al proyecto, y finalmente le des 'Build'.

Comment: Tendrá algo que ver , que solo estoy utilizando la versión trial?

Comment: Ya se te expiró? Has actualizado?

Comment: Tengo instalada la versión hace 5 días

Comment: agrega todos los detalles que realizaste para poder ayudarte. Saludos :D